# KDE 4 to 5: ServiceMenus moved directory - where to?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, customization, dolphin, kde5

I defined a lot of `.desktop` files to create context menu entries in Dolphin. Since upgrade to Kubuntu 15.10 (KDE 5) the menu entries disappeared.

I found out that KDE 5 moved the place where to store them: 
From `~/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus` to `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus`

I also tried `~/.kde/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus` (soft-linked my old dir)

But none of them work. 
Installing additional Services through the Dolphin GUI keeps installing to the old dir.

System: 
Kubuntu 15.10, `kde4-config --localprefix` says `/home/jan/.kde/`,  Dolphin Version 4:15.08.2-0ubuntu1

Why is there no `kde5-config`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No KDE5**

There are:

- KDE Frameworks 5 (KF5)
- Plasma 5
- KDE Applications

So the services are at:

```
kf5-config --path services
```

The new KF5 service menus are at:

~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/

and

/usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/

More of the KF5 paths:

Kubuntu Forums - KF5 Service Menus - https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?25740-Service-Menus-with-Dolphin&p=367207&viewfull=1#post367207

KDE Forums - Service Menus Missing: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=223&t=128621

The KDE (KF5) is using: XDG Base Directory Specification - http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Comment: kf5-config reports exactly this path. I put the files there but it still does not work: The Service-Submenu just does not show up.

Comment: I have ark_addtoservicemenu.desktop under `/usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/`. I tried to move it to `/usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/`. None of the locations is working, nothing shows up in Dolphin 15.08. Dolphin must be looking somewhere else.

Comment: This is an easily reproducible bug in Kubuntu 15.10. Dolphin and Ark are preinstalled on the live ISO. After booting from the live ISO one can see that the context menu for Ark is not showing in Dolphin.

Comment: Yes, it was a bug in Kubuntu 15.10. Now I have a fresh install of 16.4 and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Since KDE Frameworks versions from 5.85, service menus files are located here:

```
~/.local/share/kio/servicemenus
/usr/share/kio/servicemenus
```

Also you can use the command to get those locations:

```
qtpaths --locate-dirs GenericDataLocation kio/servicemenus
```

source: https://develop.kde.org/docs/apps/dolphin/service-menus/